# Why can't i pass this value into my action?

Tags: java, struts, setter

I have a CreateAction class with:

```
private String idSupplier;
public String getIdSupplier() {
    return idSupplier;
}

public void setIdSupplier(String idSupplier) {
    this.idSupplier = idSupplier;
}
```

In my form, among other things, i have :

```
<option class="selectSupplier" name="idSupplier" value="' + supp._id + '">
```

I'd like to fetch my value field in my action class. But when I use a system.out.println(idSupplier) it prints "null". However when I console.log(supp._id) in my javascript I have the proper value.

Other fields in my form are properly set.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong, i was trying to get the value of an option based on the option name.

But the setter is based on the select name.

So in my case i had:

```
<select>
    <option name="idSupplier" value="XX">
</select>
```

But i should have:

```
<select name="idSupplier">
    <option value="XX">
</select>
```